# Swift 4, Generics why do I need to cast to T here?

Tags: swift, generics

When running this code in Swift 4, The compiler throws the following error:

```
"Cannot convert return expression of type 'Comment?' to return type '_?', when running this code in a playground:
```

```swift
import UIKit

class Comment {}
class Other {}

func itemForSelectedTabIndex<T>(index: Int, type: T.Type) -> T? {
    return (type is Comment.Type) ? getComment() : getOther() 
}


func getComment() -> Comment {
    return Comment()
}

func getOther() -> Other {
    return Other()
}

let thing = itemForSelectedTabIndex(index: 0, type: Other.self)
```

In order to make this work, I need to cast the return value as generic, like this:

```swift
return (type is Comment.Type) ? getComment() as! T : getOther() as! T
```

Could someone explain the logic behind this?

If the expected return value is a 'Generic', and basically it won't matter what type I return, why the compiler complains about it?   Shouldn't this work without casting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics aren't some magical wildcards that can just have any value at any time.

When you call`itemForSelectedTabIndex(index: 0, type: Comment.self)`, `T` is inferred to `Comment`. Likewise, for `Other`.

When `T` has been inferred to `Comment`, the same value of `T` is consistent throughout everywhere it's used. Thus, the return value must be of type `Comment` (or a sub-type).

Another is with your expression `(type is Comment.Type) ? getComment() : getOther()`. There are 2 cases, and neither of them are valid:

1. `type` is `Comment.Type`: `getComment()` returns a `Comment`, a type that is compatible with the value of `T`, which is `Comment`. But, the two operands of the conditional operator have no common supertype. That's not valid.
2. `type` is ***not*** `Comment.Type`: `getOther()` returns an `Other`, which may or may not be compatible with `T`. All we know about `T` is that it is not comment. This doesn't mean it's necessarily `Other`. It can be any other type, like `Int`. Thus, this return expression fails.

What you need is a common supertype of both types you wish to return. Most probably, a protocol is the correct choice (rather than a shared superclass):

```
protocol TabItem {}

class Comment {}
class Other {}

func itemForSelectedTabIndex<T: TabItem>(index: Int, type: T.Type) -> TabItem {
    return getCommentOrOtherOrSomethingElse()
}
```